# How would one implement a sliding 2 button menu like this from Lift?

Tags: iphone, ios

https://i.stack.imgur.com/56gqE.jpg
Can't post the image on the site but there it is.

I have been trying to find if this is a template or a separate nib file ala the page turn animation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called a `UIActionSheet`. It is created entirely in code, so it's limited to some pretty simple stuff (i.e. a few buttons, one of which is the cancel button, and one of which can be marked "destructive"). Just consult the documentation for the `UIActionSheet` class; it tells you all there is to know about it.

Also, here's the discussion in my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch26.html#_action_sheet